# Given $p(x)$ to be a polynomial with non negetive integral coefficients, if $p(1)=5$ and $p(5)=151$, find possible values of $p(4)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Given $p(x)$ to be a polynomial with non negetive integral coefficients, if $p(1)=5$ and $p(5)=151$, find possible values of $p(4)$.

As there was no mention of the degree/number of terms of the polynomial in the question, I looked for to somehow bound the degree/number of terms in it.

As the coefficients can only be a whole number, the maximum number of coefficients should be 5 (even if there are other coefficients, they would be zero so they won't matter in the value of the polynomial). I tried making progress with this idea but got stuck.

Comment: Hint: $\,p(a)-p(b)\,$ must be a multiple of $\,a-b\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Which means there is no integer coefficient polynomial with $p(1) = 5$ and $p(5) = 151$, since $4\not | 146$

Comment: @dxiv how to prove it? Is it a theorem or something?

Comment: @OlympiadRunner $\;a-b \,\mid\, a^k-b^k\,$ for every integer $\,k \ge 1\,$, think the difference of powers identity.

Comment: Hint:  $ \ 5^3 \ < \ 151 \ < \ 5^4 \ \ ; $ since the coefficients are non-negative (the sum of which is $ \ 5 \ ) \ , \ $  there are only so many ways to construct such polynomials .